# Upload File, um de cada vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um duvida de como mandar uma file de cada vez depois do anterior estar completo (tenho um input múltiplo) mas ao mandar manda um de cada vez mas (se os ficheiros forem grandes manda os dois ao mesmo tempo e a **progress bar** fica a balançar de uma % para outra por causa de estarem 2 ou mais o mesmo tempo), eu queria que passa-se ao próximo upload só depois do primeiro ter feito upload.

```
(function () {
    var fileCatcher = document.getElementById('file-catcher');
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
    var fileListDisplay = document.getElementById('file-list-display');

    var fileList = [];
    var renderFileList, sendFile;


  fileCatcher.addEventListener('submit', function (evnt) {
    evnt.preventDefault();
    fileList.forEach(function (file,index) {//meti index aqui
            sendFile(file,index);//meti index aqui
    });
  });

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (evnt) {
        fileList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
    }
    renderFileList();
  });

  renderFileList = function () {
    fileListDisplay.innerHTML = '';
    fileList.forEach(function (file, index) {
        var fileDisplayEl = document.createElement('p');
      fileDisplayEl.innerHTML = (index + 1) + ': ' + file.name;
      fileListDisplay.appendChild(fileDisplayEl);
      $("#howmany").html(index + 1);
    });
  };

  sendFile = function (file,index) {//meti o index aqui
    var formData = new FormData();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();


//console.log(file);

request.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(e){



    var percent = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total * 100)

    //document.querySelector('#progress').innerHTML = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total * 100) + '%';
    $('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%')
    $('.progress-bar').html('<div id="progress-status">'+percent+'%- '+ $('#donee').html() + ' de ' + $('#howmany').html() +' Completos</div>')
    $('#percenttt').html(percent);



},false)


formData.set('file', file);
request.open("POST", 'https://1fiafqj.oloadcdn.net/uls/LUeG8UDnFMyzix84');
request.send(formData);

   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) 
    {
                $("#donee").html(index + 1);

                    //console.log(http.responseText);
                    //$('#logs').text(request.responseText);
                    console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText));//imprime em Json
                    $(".progress-bar").addClass("progress-bar-success");
                    $(".progress-bar").removeClass("active");
                    $(".progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">'+ $('#percenttt').html() +'% - '+ $('#donee').html() + ' de ' + $('#howmany').html() +' Completos</div>');
                    //console.log($('.progress-bar').width());          
    }
}
};
})();
```

Comment: Não acho uma boa idéia fazer o upload em queue neste caso porque como você mesmo disse, o ficheiros (arquivos) são grandes, então o usuário dessa interação vai perder menos tempo se os processos forem executados em paralelo.

Comment: Sobre a porcentagem, para ela dar certo, você precisa fazer duas coisas bem simples. A primeira é somar os bytes dos arquivos que estão subindo. A segunda é incrementar em outra variável, os bytes enviados dos dois arquivos e calcula a porcentagem dos bytes enviados sobre o total. Ah e use `Math.floor` q da um resultado melhor a visualização do progresso.

Comment: Essa forma também é boa , mas também gostava de saber fazer em queue porque em vez de upload ser dividido por duas tarefas era apenas 1(em vez de estar a usar 5 mb numa e 5 mb noutra ta usar 10 sempre numa).